# VBA - AutoFilter to append weekend dates from a RawData Sheet to a Weekend Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a filter that as above, copies a list of data to diferrent parts of my workbook - so far I have All, Day, Evening and Night - All is done easily enough as it just copies the whole data set, Day Evening and Night are done through the Time - I have a set of cells where you can set the limits of what you consider these variables to be e.g. Day is from 0700 - 1900, Evening - 1900-2200 and Night - 2200 - 0700.

My RawData is arranged like this - Date l Time l Windspeed l WindDirection l Otherdata

Can anyone suggest a way that i can filter out the weekends using

```
.AutoFilter
```

?

Here is the code I have so far -

```
'Set filters for daytime, evening and nighttime period
'__________________________________________________________

'all
tblArr(1).Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

'day
tblArr(2).Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
tblArr(2).Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D21").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("F21").Value

'evening
tblArr(3).Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
tblArr(3).Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D23").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("F23").Value

'night
tblArr(4).Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
tblArr(4).Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D25").Value, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<" & Sheets("Raw Data").Range("F25").Value
```

the tblArr(number) is the range that i am sending my filtered data to.

Please dont suggest to do loops as there are later data processes that require this section to be done by filtering

Any help much apprichiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to make amendments to the raw data sheet then you could add a new column containing a formula such as `=WEEKDAY(...)` - You could then use the same filtering method to isolate 7 (Sat) and 1 (Sun) - Or exclude them.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go!

Comment: i am trying to do what you have suggested to, but to do this is need to add this `=weekend(` column to a named range, i can access the name manager and get to edit - but i cannot change what it "refers to"

Comment: @lewisthegruffalo can you delete the item from the name manager and recreate it? It may also be that one or more sheets (or the workbook itself) is protected from changes?

Comment: yeah there is rather a cryptic version of the workbook with passwords and such like